# Phaser bitmap multiply does not affect sprites

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Hi I'm trying to make a basic lightning system using bitmap multiply in PhaserJS. How ever I'm having trouble with the fact that the bitmap does not darken my sprites. How would I achieve this?

I create the bitmap like so in the games create function.

```
// Shadow
this.bitmap = this.game.add.bitmapData(
  this.game.width+100,
  this.game.height+100
);
this.lightBitmap = this.game.add.image(0, 0, this.bitmap);
this.lightBitmap.blendMode = Phaser.blendModes.MULTIPLY;
```

I then fill it and paint it every frame in the update function.

```
this.bitmap.fill(20, 20, 20, 1);
this.lightBitmap.x = this.camera.x-50;
this.lightBitmap.y = this.camera.y-50;
this.bitmap.dirty = true;
```

Here is an image that shows what happens. I painted the shadow on half screen only to illustrate that it does not darken the sprites. The dirt tiles and the purple player are the sprites I want it to affect.

[image]

How can I make it darken the sprites as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because of the order you are adding your images. You should add the shadow as the last one if you want to affect to all your elements. Or you can always use [bringToTop](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.6/Phaser.Component.BringToTop.html) method.

Take a look at this example:

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(500, 500, Phaser.AUTO, 'game');
var mainState = { 
  preload:function(){
      var dataURI = 'data:image/png;base64,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'
      var data = new Image();
      data.src = dataURI;
      game.cache.addImage('car', dataURI, data);

      var dataURI2 = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
      var data2 = new Image();
      data2.src = dataURI2;
      game.cache.addImage('wood', dataURI2, data2);
},

create:function(){
 game.stage.backgroundColor = "#4488AA";
 this.bitmap = game.add.bitmapData(
      200,
      200
    );
   this.lightBitmap = game.add.image(0, 0, this.bitmap);
 this.lightBitmap.blendMode = Phaser.blendModes.MULTIPLY;

    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    this.car =this.game.add.sprite(game.world.centerX,game.world.centerY,'car');
    this.car.anchor.setTo(0.5,0.5);

    game.physics.arcade.enable(this.car);
      
  
    game.physics.arcade.enable(this.car);                     
   
    platforms = game.add.group();
    platforms.enableBody = true;

    var ground = platforms.create(100,100, 'wood');
   var ground2 = platforms.create(400,400, 'wood');
    ground.body.immovable = true;
   ground2.body.immovable = true;
  
    
},

update:function(){
    this.car.body.velocity.x =0;
    this.car.body.velocity.y = 0;
    if(game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT)){
        this.car.body.velocity.x = -100;
    }
    if(game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT)){
        this.car.body.velocity.x = 100;
    }
    if(game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.UP)){
       this.car.body.velocity.y = -100;
    }
    if(game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN)){
       
       this.car.body.velocity.y = 100;
    }
       
    
    this.bitmap.fill(50, 50, 50, 1);
    this.lightBitmap.x = this.car.body.x-50;
    this.lightBitmap.y = this.car.body.y-50;
    this.bitmap.dirty = true;
    game.world.bringToTop(this.lightBitmap);
},
};
game.state.add('main', mainState);  
game.state.start('main');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.4/phaser.min.js"></script>
<div id="game"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you saved me a lot of time!